# What are the downsides of using random ROWIDs in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, random, rowid

I'm planning to implement a randomized rowids for every new rows instead of default sequential rowids. I'm working on a web project and I don't want to expose the number of rows to the public. I have considered several approaches to provide privacy such as generating random string as UNIQUE key and using simple integer encryption before sending the rowid to visitors.

However, I would appreciate the answer would be about using the randomized rowids instead. I plan to insert one dummy row for all of my tables with rowid = MAX_ROWID so that each new rows inserted to the tables will get random rowids, a documented behavior in SQLite3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main downside is that random doesn't mean unique. If you use random rowIDs you'll have to check that each additional row's ID doesn't match any preexisting row's ID and if it does, get a new one. If you have many rows, the chances of getting the same ID twice is greater, which will require you to recalculate a random number.

A possible solution: You said you wanted to hide the number of rows to the public. If that is the only issue you can randomize the first row's ID and then keep the other row's IDs sequential. In this way there is no way to know how many rows there are. If the user gets all the rows in a certain situation he will of course be able to count the rows and know how many they are but no randomization of the row IDs will help you against this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution would be to take advantage of the algorithm used by sqlite for determining the next rowid.

That is generally the rowid will be 1 greater than the previous, that is until the maximum value is obtained, then as long as **AUTOINCREMENT isn't coded** SQLite will try to find an unused/free value.

So if you insert a row with that value then subsequent rows will not be sequential.

> If no ROWID is specified on the insert, or if the specified ROWID has
>   a value of NULL, then an appropriate ROWID is created automatically.
>   The usual algorithm is to give the newly created row a ROWID that is
>   one larger than the largest ROWID in the table prior to the insert. If
>   the table is initially empty, then a ROWID of 1 is used. If the
>   largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer
>   (9223372036854775807) then the database engine starts picking positive
>   candidate ROWIDs at random until it finds one that is not previously
>   used. If no unused ROWID can be found after a reasonable number of
>   attempts, the insert operation fails with an SQLITE_FULL error. If no
>   negative ROWID values are inserted explicitly, then automatically
>   generated ROWID values will always be greater than zero.[SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

For example consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS randid;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS randid (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , data TEXT);

-- INSERT A ROW using the highest possible value for the ID 
INSERT INTO randid VALUES(9223372036854775807,'dummy'); -- <<<<<<<<<< THE BASIS OF THIS METHODOLOGY

-- insert some more data letting SQLite generate the ID
INSERT INTO randid (data) VALUES('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('a'),('b'),('c'),('d'),('a'),('b'),('c'),('d');

-- get the resultant data from the table
SELECT * FROM randid;
```

### Result from 1st run :-

[image]

### Result from another run :-

[image]

With the exception of the last row (which was the first added), you can't even easily ascertain the insertion order.

> What are the downsides of using random rowids in SQLite?

I don't believe there would a noticeable impact by using the above, perhaps a marginal amount of extra time generating and then trying the random number to use, which would get marginally longer as there were fewer free numbers *(might be worthwhile adding a second initial row using -9223372036854775808, which would then open up the use of negative number and thus make more values available)*. However there might also be gains as I believe distributed inserts make for a more efficient B-Tree (Index).

You mention **rowid**, the above is using an alias of the **rowid** and although not hidden like a **rowid** the value would serve little meaning if it were made visible (why would you? (that's rhetoric)).

**However** one disadvantage with **rowid**, which could initially be used in the same way, **is that a VACUUM renumbers all rowids** if the rowid column does not have have an alias, which would undo the randomness.